# CKFinder TypeError: t.event.special.swipe is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, ckeditor, ckfinder

When using CKFinder 3.2.0 on Firefox 44.0 I receive the following error.
It happens only on Firefox and on Chrome is completely fine.

Any idea what could cause it and how to fix it?

```
TypeError: t.event.special.swipe is undefined
Stack trace:
CKFinder</<._setup/</<.init@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:8:8
CKFinder</<._setup/</<.start/</<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:19:9706
newContext/y.execCb@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:26980
newContext/C.prototype.check@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:20584
newContext/C.prototype.enable@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23528
newContext/C.prototype.init@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:19790
o/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:25339
setTimeout handler*CKFinder</<._setup/</</req.nextTick<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:29067
o@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:25278
CKFinder</<._setup/</</requirejs@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:28955
CKFinder</<._setup/</<.start/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:19:9598
n.Callbacks/j@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/libs/jquery.js?ver=js6uhv:2:26920
n.Callbacks/k.fireWith@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/libs/jquery.js?ver=js6uhv:2:27738
.Deferred/</e[f[0]]@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/libs/jquery.js?ver=js6uhv:2:28704
CKFinder</<._setup/</r.init/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:7:29367
s@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:7:27199
newContext/y.execCb@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:26980
newContext/C.prototype.check@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:20584
newContext/C.prototype.enable/</<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23189
bind/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:14778
newContext/C.prototype.emit/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23667
each@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:14253
newContext/C.prototype.emit@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23635
newContext/C.prototype.check@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:21305
newContext/C.prototype.enable@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23528
newContext/C.prototype.init@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:19790
newContext/C.prototype.callPlugin/</r<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:22166
bind/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:14778
CKFinder</<._setup/</t.finishLoad@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:9:24377
CKFinder</<._setup/</t.load/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:9:24651
CKFinder</<._setup/</t.get/s.onreadystatechange@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:9:25864
EventHandlerNonNull*CKFinder</<._setup/</t.get@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:9:25720
CKFinder</<._setup/</t.load@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:9:24631
newContext/C.prototype.callPlugin/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:22740
bind/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:14778
u@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:17104
newContext/C.prototype.callPlugin@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:21493
newContext/C.prototype.fetch@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:20194
newContext/C.prototype.check@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:21399
newContext/C.prototype.enable@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23528
newContext/y.enable@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:26027
newContext/C.prototype.enable/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23388
bind/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:14778
each@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:14253
newContext/C.prototype.enable@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:22878
newContext/C.prototype.init@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:19790
o/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:25339
setTimeout handler*CKFinder</<._setup/</</req.nextTick<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:29067
o@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:25278
CKFinder</<._setup/</</requirejs@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:28955
i@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:7:27411
CKFinder</<._setup/</r.init@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:7:27819
CKFinder</<._setup/</<.start@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:19:9399
o/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:19:12310
newContext/y.execCb@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:26980
newContext/C.prototype.check@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:20584
newContext/C.prototype.enable/</<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23189
bind/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:14778
newContext/C.prototype.emit/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23667
each@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:14253
newContext/C.prototype.emit@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23635
newContext/C.prototype.check@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:21305
newContext/C.prototype.enable/</<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23189
bind/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:14778
newContext/C.prototype.emit/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23667
each@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:14253
newContext/C.prototype.emit@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23635
newContext/C.prototype.check@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:21305
newContext/C.prototype.enable/</<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23189
bind/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:14778
newContext/C.prototype.emit/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23667
each@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:14253
newContext/C.prototype.emit@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23635
newContext/C.prototype.check@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:21305
newContext/C.prototype.enable/</<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23189
bind/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:14778
newContext/C.prototype.emit/<@https://10.10.10.20/ckfinder/ckfinder.js:5:23667
```

Comment: AFAIR this event is from jQuery mobile so maybe there was some problems with loading jquery mobile's js file. Also in which mode did you encounter that (widget, popup, modal)?

Comment: @jodator thanks for your comment, I am using widget mode. I have notice jQuery mobile is included inside lib in ckFinder.... any idea or work around how to fix it?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this on my machine using HTPS and/or slower connections but I was unable to reproduce it on dev version (3.3) nor on https://cksource.com/ckfinder/demo#widget site (version 3.2). Thus you should check in dev console (F12) - network tab - if jquery mobile file is loaded during start (no 404 errors, etc). It should be available at: https://1010.10.20/ckfinder/libs/jquery.mobile.js judging on that stack trace.

Comment: I've double check this, on HTPS and HTP, same error, we are evaluating ckfinder within a dojo 1.10 application. Are you aware of any issue with Dojo? Any other idea where to investigate this issue? Thanks for your support!

Comment: I have found out that the error appears when we try to initialized ckfinder widget inside a div which has inline style property display:none

Comment: Ugh.. I can reproduce this but I cannot tell you why Firefox does it right now. I've submitted bug report for this: https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder/issues/294. As for now the only solution is to initialize CKFinder when it is needed in visible div as this happen only in Firefox.

Comment: I've also reported a bug for jQuery mobile: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8383 since similar issue is reproducible on pure jQuery mobile app.

Answer (score 5):

As for now the problem resides in the library that is used by CKFinder - [jQuery mobile isn't properly initialized when its frame is located inside a hidden `<div>`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8383) (with `style="display:none"`).

To overcome this issue you can try another approach to hide the CKFinder application by setting zero height for you `<div>` and setting `overflow` to `hidden`.

```
<div id="ckfinder" style="height:0;overflow: hidden;"></div>

<button id="show">show CKFinder</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById('show' ).onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById('ckfinder' ).style.height = 'auto';
    };

    CKFinder.widget( 'ckfinder', {
        width: '100%',
        height: 600
    } );

</script>
```